# Why PyCharm Terminal returnung different results?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Here is similar question [pycharm terminal and run giving different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146596/pycharm-terminal-and-run-giving-different-results) as you may see there was problem with Python versions.
Here what I have: (difference in the last lines output)

Ubuntu Terminal:

```
***@***:~/Documents/Coding/Django/myfirst$ python3 manage.py shell
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from articles.models import Article, Comment
>>> a = Article.objects.get(id = 1)
>>> a
<Article: How to...?>
>>> a.comment_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Comment: John>, <Comment: Jack>, <Comment: Nelson>, <Comment: Bill>]>
```

PyCharm Terminal:

```
***@***:~/Documents/Coding/Django/myfirst$ python3 manage.py shell
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from articles.models import Article, Comment
>>> a = Article.objects.get(id = 1)
>>> a.id
1
>>> a.article_Title
'How to...?'
>>> a.comment_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Comment: Comment object (1)>, <Comment: Comment object (2)>, <Comment: Comment object (3)>]>
```

So it`s returning id of Comment instead of Name.

Many thanks for any advice!

Adding Code from manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you please show the manage.py file?

Comment: Code from manage.py added. Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting but I guess, the only difference is the way interactive console prints objects. It's like python shell:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7f1466211630>
```

vs ipython

```
<__main__.A at 0x7f5a270fb4e0>
```

I'll try to find out why it's happening.

Comment: Thank you for your attention mate!